# Where is pixel per unit(sprite)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity , so plz forgive me asking this question. However, I can't find any solution online. My question is: How to find the texture button and thus able to change the value in pixel per unit. 
That is no such thing (pixel per unity) on the right-hand side(the inspector). neither in debug mode nor in normal mode . Plz tell me the solution with clear explaination. Thank in advance!

Afterwards, I thought I should have installed some package from package manager so that I can change the value of pixel per unit.Sadly, it seems that it is unrelated.

----let me clarify that , i am not looking for the reference pixel per unit of canvas scaler

Comment: I think it's on a `Canvas` component that you will find a `Pixel per unit` check box.

Comment: Can't find it by adding component -canvas

Comment: I right clicked inside a `Hierarchy` window -> `UI` -> `Canvas`  and it will instantiate me a built-in canvas prefab. There I can see it has a `CanvasScaler` component. It has a `Reference Pixels Per Unit`. Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: sorry for answering you late . it seems that you are talking about the ref pixel per unit about canvas scaler .and right now I am talking about the pixel per unit of sprite .And I find that they are totally different things . (it should be)

Comment: Should I delete the post ??

Answer (score 1):

I finally find the solution by myself!In fact , I should click on the item in asset area(bottom place) , instead of that in hierarchy , it will show different inspectors and then you can find pixel per unit !!(solution)

Comment: Good Job, please check every possible answer to your question before posting it on any forum. Happy coding.